# Phrase simple strings in MS SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, phrase

I have a code string where codes are connected with AND, OR and [parenthesis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%28#Parentheses_.28_.29).

I'd like to split them so that I get multiple records where the codes are only connected by AND

AND is represented by + and OR is represented by /

If for example I have the following two records

```
Phrase        Translates to:
=======       ==============
(A/B)+C       (A OR B) AND C
(D+E)/F       (D AND E) OR F
```

The result should be

```
Expression    Translates to:
=======       ==============
A+C           A AND C
B+C           B AND C

D+E           D AND E
F             F
```

My SQL Syntax looks like:

```
CREATE TABLE Code_Conditions(
  Part AS CHAR(10),
  Condition AS VARCHAR(255)
);

CREATE TABLE Product(
  Product_ID AS INT PRIMARY KEY,
  Code_String AS VARCHAR(255)
);

CREATE TABLE Product_Parts(
  Product_ID AS INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Product (Product_ID),
  Part AS CHAR(10)
);


INSERT INTO Code_Conditions (Part, Condition) VALUES ('PartA', '(A/B)+C');
INSERT INTO Code_Conditions (Part, Condition) VALUES ('PartB', '(D+E)/F');

INSERT INTO Product(Product_ID, Code_String) VALUES ( 1, 'A+B+D');
INSERT INTO Product(Product_ID, Code_String) VALUES ( 2, 'B+C+F');
INSERT INTO Product(Product_ID, Code_String) VALUES ( 3, 'B+C+D');
```

Product 1 should match no parts
Product 2 should match PartA and PartB
Product 3 should match PartA

Thank you for any help.

Comment: can you show us a sqlfiddle that demonstrates the table structure and a query that you execute?

Comment: Are you sure your example is correct? I don't see how `(A/B)+C` would result in `A+C` and `A+B`?

Comment: @RobIII he didn't say every line feed represents a AND. But anyway I don't think there's any logic thing in it, seeing the lonely F line.

Comment: Can you elaborate as to why this is sql/sql-server relevant?

Comment: @Sebas Where did I say that, or hint at, a new line representing an AND? The question actually states "I have the following two records" so it seems to me it's safe to assume each line is a separate record. But I do agree with you, which was the reason for my comment as well, that there's no logic in the question (even after the edit user2216002 made).

Comment: does your solution need to be in sql or can you do it in java/c#/ruby/etc?

Comment: Ah, I see the logic now: `(A OR B) AND C` => `A AND C` & `B AND C`; `(D AND E) OR F` => `D AND E` & `F`.

Comment: I am guessing that the logic is any combination of codes that causes the original statement to evaluate to TRUE.  I still can't think of a SQL-ish way to solve it, but I think that is the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the very little information we have, and from the little sense I'm able to make of it, I have to guess that you should take a look at [User Defined Functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191165%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) (UDF). See also [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164062.aspx) article.

**Edit**
[I see the logic now](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15661686/phrase-simple-strings-in-ms-sql#comment22228640_15661686) after user2216002's edit. I have clarified the question a bit more.

This *can* be done using an UDF but I would recommend against it for performance reasons on large(r) tables and the mere fact that the code won't be very 'pretty'. I would recommend first to see if [normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) on the database would help solve storing these 'phrases' in a more efficient way.

If you insist on a "SQL-Only" solution you will have to write an [expression parser](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing_expression_grammar) in T-SQL which, again, won't be pretty and a lot of work to get it right. If the 'phrases' (or rather: expressions) aren't any more complicated than the examples in the question you could take some shortcuts.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I get the phrase from a different System and try to split it up in SQL. But I guess it would be easier to write the split function in Phyton and then import it into the database.

Comment: Just to make sure you understand: storing the conditions as a string is probably not the way to go. It actually ̶s̶̶m̶̶e̶̶l̶̶l̶̶s̶ ̶l̶̶i̶̶k̶̶e̶  is an [Anti-pattern](http://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/sql-antipatterns-strike-back). You *could* have a look at [CLR UDF's](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2kae45k(v=vs.80).aspx) that might be able to relieve some of the T-SQL mess you're about to create if you keep insisting on your chosen path; consider it a compromise.